# Bash: grep return true for all lines

Tags: bash, grep

I have a few lines (I don'ẗ know how many). I send them through a pipe to `grep`. I need to find out if all the lines were selected by `grep`. Then I need to write OK (if they were all selected) or Not OK. How can I to do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Where you searching for the lines that you are piping through?  From another file?

Comment: I've made a guess at what you are seeking to ask — please explain more if I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to use the `-v` (`--invert-match`) flag, which tells `grep` to search for lines that *don't* match your pattern.

You can combine that with the `-q` (`--quiet` or `--silent`) flag, which tells `grep` to not actually emit any output, and to just exit successfully if it finds any lines that it *would* have output.

Then you can just examine the exit status: zero ("success" / "true") if any lines didn't match your pattern, nonzero ("failure" / "false") otherwise. So:

```
if ... | grep -qv ... ; then
    echo Not OK
else
    echo OK
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two files `file1` and `file2`, you can check if all lines of `file1` are in `file2` with this:

```
if ! grep -qvxFf file2 file1; then
  echo "All lines of file1 are present in file2'
else
  echo "Some lines of file1 are not present in file2'
fi
```

If `file1` comes from a command execution, then use process substitution:

```
if ! grep -qvxFf file2 <(file1-command); then
  echo "All lines are present in file2'
else
  echo "Some lines are not present in file2'
fi
```

- `x` matches the entire line
- `F` treats the lines as strings, not patterns

When all lines in `file1` match at least one line in `file2`, `grep -qvxFf file2 file1` gives an exit code of 1, indicating that match returned no output, `-v` (inverse match) is in effect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you currently have:

```
some-process-generating-lines |
grep -e 'some selection criterion'
```

and you want check whether the number of lines passed into `grep` is the same as the number of lines coming out of it — whether every input line satisfies the selection criterion.

You need to be able able to count both the lines in and the lines out.  Counting lines out is easy — pass the output through `wc -l` and capture the whole result.

```
lines_out=$(some-process-generating-lines |
            grep -e 'some selection criterion' |
            wc -l)
```

Counting the lines in is modestly harder.  The simplest approach is to have the `tee` command create a copy of the input data to `grep` and then count that:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/soq.XXXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmpfile; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

lines_out=$(some-process-generating-lines |
            tee $tmpfile |
            grep -e 'some selection criterion' |
            wc -l)
lines_in=$(wc -l <$tmpfile)

rm -f $tmpfile
trap 0 1 2 3 13 15

if [ "$lines_in" = "$lines_out" ]
then echo OK
else echo Not OK
fi
```

The `trap` stuff ensures (or tries to ensure) that the temporary file is cleaned up even if the process is interrupted (or sent a quit, hangup, pipe or terminate signal).  The `mktemp` command generates a unique file name.  The rest is fairly straight-forward, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is defined by this:

```
some-process-generating-lines |
    grep -E 'some selection criterion'
```

And you want to count the lines in and out, you could do something like this:
The `printf "aaa\nbbb\nccc\n"` is just an example of code generating output.

```
#!/bin/bash

f() { cat "$1" | tee "$x" | grep -E "aaa|bbb" >"$y"; }

x=>( a=$(wc -l); echo "Lines in : $a") \
    y=>( b=$(wc -l); echo "Lines out: $b") \
        f <(printf "aaa\nbbb\nccc\n")
```

Or the option without cat (less easy to follow but more technically correct):

```
f() { <"$1" tee "$x" | grep -E "aaa|bbb" >"$y"; }
```

On execution the output will be:

```
$ ./script.sh
Lines out: 2
Lines in : 3
```

No files to clean after use.

Comment: You definitely want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) there.

Comment: @tripleee Done (well, half of it, because I find that even less easy to follow).